# outer declaration of nested two template classes

Tags: c++, templates

assume we have a template class named **outer** and inside this template class we declare a template class named **inner**.

```
template <typename T>
class outer{

template <typename U> class inner;

};
```

My questions;

- **1) How to forward declare a template class inside the outer one?**
- **2) How to define template inner class after the template outer class?**

According to duplicate answers,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "forward_list.h"

template <typename T>
class outer{
    template <typename U> class inner;
private:
    inner<T> innerItem;
public:
    void doSomething(){
        innerItem.print();
    }

};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
class outer<T>::inner{
public:
    void print(){std::cout << "inner print\n";}

};


int main(int argc, char ** argv){


    outer<int> a;
    a.doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please example with some code what you are trying to do.  It makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not that I really like to draw dupes from _@VFM_ ;-) but that one seems to answer the question with standard reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver i have added an example.

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran Your forward declaration looks just fine. Can you add a [MCVE] of what you want to achieve and how it fails?

Comment: Eventually my intention is to create a linked list whose node is declared inside the outer list class. i hope that i am in the right way.

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran When I [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5438bb09e603382) your example now (removing the unrelated `#include` statement), it just works fine, no? I don't get what's your concern actually.